# Energia compilation error :exit status 1 Error compiling for board MSP-EXP430FR4133LP

Tags: msp430

I am trying to code for msp430 using energia .

Can anyone help me understand the error?

> Energia: 1.6.10E18 (Windows 8.1), Board: "MSP-EXP430FR4133LP"
>
> msp430-g++: error:
>   islam\Desktop\energia-1.6.10E18\hardware\tools\msp430/include: No such
>   file or directory
>
> exit status 1 Error compiling for board MSP-EXP430FR4133LP.
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cut your **energia-1.6.10E18** folder and paste it in

`> C:\IDE\energia\` directory.

Run your `energia.exe` file from  `C:\IDE\energia\energia-1.6.10E18\` and it will work.

> **N.B:** No spacing between words in url 
>   ( i.e `c:/sifatul islam/energia` )

Answer (score 1):

Even i had the same issue and the above solutions did not work for me, however i switched to Energia version 17 and it worked smoothly.